# Moralis API sort query numerically instead of 0, 10, 100, 1001, 1002

Tags: ethereum, decentralized-applications, moralis

This is for the Moralis API to make Ethereum apps. I am using getAllTokenIds() to pull data for an NFT collection, and storing the data in Moralis database.

using this line: query.ascending(“tokenId”);

my results are coming in with the token ids (0, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 10001, 10002, 10003 …) how do I make it so my order for token Ids is (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 …)?

I have tried to look up ways to convert my token Ids columns into number format, but I am not sure if there is a way to do it in the Moralis database.

Answer (score 0):

GM there,

usually the `tokenId` returned will be string, so it will order it like a string

So one solutions would be after you pushed the result to Moralis DB, run `beforeSave` or `afterSave` to make a new column that save the integer version of the `tokenId`s

Alternatively, convert those `tokenId`s to integer first before pushing then to Moralis DB

Let me know if you found something else

Cheers~